# Cancel new line preventions in R's glue package

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, r-glue

In the glue package you *"can use \\ at the end of a line to prevent adding a newline"*. In LaTeX \\ is the new line symbol.

**I am looking for a better solution than my current one**

```
glue_data(iris,
"\\midrule
\\textbf{{{mean(Petal.Length)}} & 820 &  100\\% \\\\
~other & 902 \\\\"
)
```

Actual output:

```
\midrule
\textbf{3.758} & 820 & 100\% \~other & 902 \\
```

Expected output:

```
\midrule
\textbf{3.758} & 820 &  100\% \\
~other & 902 \\
```

My current ugly and error-prone fix:

```
glue_data(iris,
"\\midrule
\\textbf{{{mean(iris$Petal.Length)}} & 820 &  100\\% \\\\\\
\n~other & 902 \\\\"
)

\midrule
\textbf{3.758} & 820 &  100\% \\
~other & 902 \\
```

Comment: `glue_data` doesn't seem designed to work with LaTeX.  Why not use some other way to insert computed values into your LaTeX (e.g. knitr Rnw files) or some other function for macro substitution?

Comment: Good point @user2554330. I like glue's overall syntax and decided I will give a try for this one project. Anyway I already found an improvement to my current solution which is passing the linebreaks in as a variable so glue doesn't interpret them: `lineb <- '\\\\'`  and then `... &  100\\% {lineb}`

Comment: You should add your `{lineb}` solution as an answer to your own question.  It looks pretty clever.

Comment: a space after `\\` but before the linebreak seems to do the job as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better method I found was to add the LaTeX linebreaks in as a variable to prevent them from being interpreted by `glue`:

```
lineb <- '\\\\'
glue_data(
  iris,
  "\\midrule
  \\textbf{{{mean(Petal.Length)}} & 820 &  100\\% {lineb}
  ~other & 902 \\\\"
)
```

**Output**

```
\midrule
\textbf{3.758} & 820 &  100\% \\
~other & 902 \\
```